# WCF/WPF DateTime returning null

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, datetime

I have a WPF app that is calling a WCF service. In the WCF service I make a call to a database and return some items, one which includes a datetime.

Here is how i'm returning the data.

```
List<MessageData> messages = new List<MessageData>();
//sql stuff
 while (reader.Read())
{
    MessageData message = new MessageData();
    message.ID = (Guid)reader["message_id"];
    message.Description = reader["subject"].ToString();
    messageData.IssuedDate = reader["issued_date"].ToString();
    message.Severity = reader["severity"].ToString();
    message.Specialty =reader["specialty"].ToString();
    messages.Add(message);
}
```

in MessageData I have specified IssuedDate as both a DateTime and a string.
Stepping through the debugger I see an actual DateTime being placed in IssuedDate.
When it comes back to the WPF app, IssuedDate is null and the value is lost.

WPF side

```
List<CWeb.MessageData> data = new CWeb.SCClient().GetMessages(messageData, Global.Token).ToList();
```

Any hints? I'm guessing it's being lost in serialization/deserialization?

**Update**
When I assign random words to IssuedDate when it's a string, example: 'why you no work'
It comes back as that string not refused to return anything in a datetime format.

Comment: You may overwriting the value retrieved from the WCF service on the UI side or you may be overwriting on the WCF side itself, furtherdown to this code?

Comment: after exiting the reader, messages is returned so it's not being overwritten on the WCF side. On the WPF side data which contains the list, all IssuedDate's are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be your contracts don't match? Maybe the client expects a `DateTime` where the service provides a `String`?

WCF is well capable of returning a `DateTime` in a data contract. So `MessageData.IssuedDate` should be `DateTime` and you could use something like this to get it from the data reader:

```
message.IssuedDate = reader["issued_date"] as DateTime? : DateTime.MinValue;
```

One more thing I noticed: The `IssuedDate` property is the only one you don't set in the `message` object, but the `messageData` object. Are you sure you're using the correct object?

Also, when returning `DateTime` as string, you should convert it into a somewhat international format you can convert back from reliably, for example `ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")`.